# PHP mail() Not Functioning

Tags: php, html, email, html-email

So, I have been working on this mail function for the last hour or so, but I can't figure out why it is not sending out the email! I have tried multiple times, altering the code and trying to make it perfect, but still, I have not received the test email...

I have HTML in my email, however, that is not the problem, as I have tested it out without the HTML.

MY PHP:

```
$to = $register_data['email'];
        $subject = "Welcome!";
        $body = '
            <html>
                <head>
                    <style>
                        body{
                            background-color: #FFF;
                            font-family: arial;
                            margin: 0;
                            padding: 0;
                        }
                        a{
                            color: inherit;
                            text-decoration: none;
                        }
                        .outer-email{
                            width: 80%;
                            height: auto;
                            margin: 0 auto;
                        }
                        .info-email{
                            width: 80%;
                            margin: 120px auto;
                        }
                        .outer-header h3{
                            font-size: 2.9em;
                            color: #151515;
                            margin: 0;
                        }
                        .inner-email{
                            margin-top: 20px;
                        }
                        .inner-email span{
                            font-size: 1.3em;
                            color: #151515;
                        }
                    </style>
                </head>
            <body>
                <div class="outer-email">
                    <div class="info-email">
                        <div class="outer-header">
                            <h3>Welcome!</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inner-email">
                            <span>Welcome, $register_data['fname'];
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
        ';
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: Domain <noreply@domain.com>';

        mail($to, 'Welcome!', $body, $headers);
```

Please don't class this as a duplicate either, because I have tested ALOT of the other forum questions on this topic, and they didn't solve my problem! :(

Thanks

EDIT:
My register function on page:

```
if(empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
            $register_data = array(
                'username'      => $_POST['username'],
                'password'      => $_POST['password'],
                'fname'         => $_POST['fname'],
                'lname'         => $_POST['lname'],
                'email'         => $_POST['email'],
                'type'          => $_POST['type'],
                'email_code'    => md5($_POST['username'] + microtime())
            );
            register($register_data, $conn);
            redirect('register.php?success');
            exit();
        } else if (empty($errors) === false)  {
            echo error_output($errors);
        }
```

UPDATE::

Ok, so I've figured out that if I upload it onto my published server, It does in fact work, so it must've been a problem on my localhost... Thanks @MarkP

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: @MarkP none, I have made sure to turn error reporting off

Comment: How are you getting this? $register_data['email']; ?

Comment: @MarkP from the register form on the other page... Would you like me to show?

Comment: try the mail function at the bottom with a hard coded email first  mail('email@email.com', 'Welcome!', $body, $headers); do you get an email?

Comment: yes, show the other form

Comment: I'll try that now... @MarkP

Comment: echo out: $_POST['email']. does it have a value?

Comment: @MarkP still doesn't want to work... :(

Comment: quick question? Are you using wordpress?

Comment: @MarkP echoing it out gives an error

Comment: @MarkP no... have never used wordpress before

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: That;s ok, wordpress has caused issues before

Comment: also change this line: if(empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) { to if(!empty($_POST) && empty($errors) ) {

Comment: @MarkP unexpected echo

Comment: Also, how are you passing the data to those variables? do you have a form?

Comment: @MarkP yes I do have a form...

Comment: can you check, have you added name="email" to the email input ?

Comment: apologies for the long questions, just trying to figure it out?

Comment: try one more thing: mail('youremail@email.com', 'Welcome!', 'body');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102120/discussion-between-markp-and-caelan-grgurovic).

Comment: @MarkP done that... haha

Answer (score 3):

Ok, After a live chat it turns out the OP is using a local server (XAMPP).

I recommended they go to [How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)

To find out how to activate the mail server.

@Caelan Grgurovic if this is the correct solution, please accept my answer so that people don't spend their time trying to figure out what the issue is.

## edit

Try this on your server

new page test.php

```
<?php
 mail('youremail@email.com', 'Welcome!', 'body');
?>
```

obv change your email, if this does not work, then you have not set up emails on your server correctly, try on a web host server.

Comment: didn't work, sorry :(

Comment: I'll try this... see how it goes :/

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's the case, but you have a syntax error in your `$body`, change

```
<span>Welcome, $register_data['fname'];
```

to

```
<span>Welcome, '.$register_data["fname"].';
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: you are not escaping the single quote surrounding `fname`

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic: One difference is that it is using string concatenation whereas the your code isn't.

Comment: @Kolunar already done this in the real code, I've just shrunk the original HTML down and forgot to concatenate..

Comment: shouldnt be a problem with his issue at the moment as he said he tried it without all that, and the mail function still didnt send.

Comment: @jsve ya, if it's a variable, then should be concatenated. answer's been updated.